# Windows + PHP 5.3.6 - Undefined function, mysql_connect?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

We have a brand new webserver upon which we installed Apache, then PHP, pointing it to Apache's conf dir, and installing all of the optional pieces. I'm now trying to get MySQL to connect, and it refuses. My PHP.ini lists the module as uncommented, and it is in the directory my extension dir is set to, but I just keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\apache\htdocs\index.php on line 8
```

I installed:

```
PHP: VC9 x86 Thread Safe (2011-Mar-22 13:27:32)

Apache: Apache 2.2

MySQL: Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer

Windows: Windows 7
```

I've added PHP to my PATH var, and have phpinfo() outputting, but I'm not sure what to look for. All of the docs I've read seem to indicate that in PHP 5.3.x+ MySQL / MySQLi support should be enabled by default.

phpinfo's mysqlnd info:

```
mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $
Compression     supported
SSL     supported
Command buffer size     4096
Read buffer size    32768
Read timeout    31536000
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    No
Tracing     n/a
```

phpinfo's configure command info:

```
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-isapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static"
```

phpinfo's loaded config file info:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
```

Inside of that, towards the bottom:

```
[dba]
;dba.default_handler=

; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
[PHP_BZ2]
extension=php_bz2.dll
[PHP_CURL]
extension=php_curl.dll
[PHP_FILEINFO]
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
[PHP_GD2]
extension=php_gd2.dll
[PHP_GETTEXT]
extension=php_gettext.dll
[PHP_GMP]
extension=php_gmp.dll
[PHP_IMAP]
extension=php_imap.dll
[PHP_INTL]
extension=php_intl.dll
[PHP_LDAP]
extension=php_ldap.dll
[PHP_MBSTRING]
extension=php_mbstring.dll
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLITE]
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
[PHP_PGSQL]
extension=php_pgsql.dll
[PHP_SOAP]
extension=php_soap.dll
[PHP_SOCKETS]
extension=php_sockets.dll
[PHP_SQLITE]
extension=php_sqlite.dll
[PHP_SQLITE3]
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
[PHP_TIDY]
extension=php_tidy.dll
[PHP_XMLRPC]
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
[PHP_EXIF]
extension=php_exif.dll
```

EDIT: So I played around with my .ini a bit, deleting it, putting junk in it, and phpinfo() kept the same info. So I actually looked hard, and I have my .ini set `upload_max_filesize` to 200M, but phpinfo says 2M. What gives? It's the exact file that phpinfo is trying to tell me is the .ini.

Comment: check if you uncommented the extension in the right php.ini. But given that there is [efforts to deprecate ext/mysql](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=131031747409271&w=2), you really shouldnt be using it anymore. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @Gordon: We are actually starting today to switch towards PDO, however, I need it to run while we convert. Also, mysqli will not load either.

Comment: There is no effort to deprecate ext/mysql. There only is an effort to encourage people to move to newer extensions, as they offer more features and are better supported.

Comment: @Mchl educating people is the first step in that effort. The goal is to deprecate it in the long run because none of the core developers want to maintain it anymore and active development has ceased for quite some time now.

Comment: Where'd the funky `[PHP_*]` ini headers come from?  Please try removing them.  They are not present in any of the (completely working) php.ini files I've seen...

Comment: No doubt. I just don't think saying 'ext/mysql will be deprecated' is the correct way to do it ;)

Comment: @Charles: They came in the default .ini

Comment: @Josh, which distribution of PHP are you using?  The official one from php.net, or one of the bundled packages like WAMP, XAMPP, etc?

Comment: @Charles: It's the distro from php.net, as I mention in my post. Thread safe for Windows.

Comment: Josh: Are you restarting Apache after changing php.ini ?

Comment: @Mchl: Yes I am, from the quick menu, and from the monitor, using a Start, Stop. I also updated my post with some weirdness I noticed about modifying the .ini

Comment: Which file you're editing? Should be the one with path in `Loaded Configuration File` row

Comment: @Josh, if you execute PHP from the command line (try running a `phpinfo()` script), does it still load the (clearly wrong) php.ini?

Comment: @Mchl: That is the one I'm editing.

Comment: @Charles: You did it! Running php from the command line revealed that there was an extra ( that was unenclosed by quotes. Man, I feel pretty silly.

Comment: And that error didn't show up in the Apache error log?

Comment: @Charles: I am looking through the logs, and each time I restarted, I see a timezone warning, then the mysql_connect() error, no syntax due to the paren listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was a parse error in the config file due to the paren in Program Files (x86) not being enclosed with quotes. Great call by Charles to suggest starting PHP from the command line!

Answer (score 2):

Most common mistake (particularly on Windows) is to forget setting up the path of "extension_dir" in the php.ini file. PHP by default assumes C:\php\ext, whereas many prefer to unzip PHP to C:\Program Files\PHP.